Do flags affect a user's ability to comment?
I recently had a problem with a user commenting excessively on a post of mine.  At first it seemed like they were trying to help, but many of their statements were verifiably false and the longer we went back and forth the more irritating it became.
At a certain point, this can begin to feel malicious. Since we cannot block such users, do flags help? Do users ever lose the ability to comment when enough flags for removal are raised?

If a user is suspended, they are unable to comment. I cannot confirm this, but mods will probably suspend a user if a user is misusing comments.

I confirm what @Fastnlight says: persistent misuse of comments may lead to a suspension (most likely after a warning to knock it off).

If the conversation turned unproductive, you are encouraged to report any comment, that legitimately should be deleted but it’s often best to hit the eject button yourself and simply stop interacting. Submitting false information through a comment isn’t likely going to result in a suspension.

As mentioned in the comments, suspensions prevent commenting. A sufficient amount  of unfriendly or harassment flags (read: unfriendly/harassment flags on 3 or more comments in a short period of time) causes an automatic mod flag, which draws in more mod attention, and often a warning and/or suspension. That's as close as you get to enough flags having consequences. We deal with it, but it's fully reactive, and when a mod has capacity to handle the flags.
Aside suspensions, dropping back under 50 rep also disables commenting, but that's only applicable in very specific circumstances. But there are no automatic systems that disable commenting after enough flags, and unfortunately, there's no way to disable only the commenting privilege.
